# What does 'Hitlerian' mean, extract from Vladimir Nabokov's Lolita

Tags: meaning, literature, lolita

> With Mr. West, retired executioner or writer of religious tracts—who cared?—I saw neighbor what’s his name, I think they are French or Swiss, meditate in his frank-windowed study over a typewriter, rather gaunt-profiled, an almost Hitlerian cowlick on his pale brow.

Excerpt From: Vladimir Nabokov. “[Lolita](https://books.google.it/books?id=S0lVyYcw8tsC&pg=PT177&lpg=PT177&dq=%22meditate%20in%20his%20frank-windowed%20study%22&source=bl&ots=m1TZaXHXFw&sig=U7aFvwmy5NKIgWHDKQkDDdkBkf8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22meditate%20in%20his%20frank-windowed%20study%22&f=false)” iBooks.

Google returned zero results for "define Hitlerian lolita"

I don't understand this reference? It can't be a reference to Hitler himself because the book was written in 1955...

Comment: 1955 is 10 years after Adolf Hitler’s death, so it certainly can be a reference to him!

Comment: *Hitlerian Lolita* isn't going to be in any dictionary, so it's a pretty pointless task asking Google to define this expression. On the other hand, the term [*Hitlerian*](https://www.google.it/search?q=Hitlerian&oq=Hitlerian&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=define+Hitlerian) is found in many dictionaries and answers your question perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

The adjective describes the cow-lick which is a feature of photographs of Hitler.  (Cow-lick describes a lock of hair which rises from the forehead and then flops forward) Nabokov uses an insulting comparison to show what H thinks about the neighbour.

Comment: [This](http://static.businessinsider.com/image/51e40d5a69bedda654000000/image.jpg) might help.

Comment: You can rollback this edit if you prefer, but I think the image does illustrate  a Hitlerian *cowlick* quite well.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, thank you, it's perfect. if that's not too nice a word.